# Error:(48, 21) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-android-api-1

I'm using Android Studio 1.1, and AP1 21 (version required as part of a course). I create a new project using the `Google Maps Activity`.

Within the automatically generated code, I get the following error message: `Error:(48, 21) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()`, in the `setUpMapIfNeeded` method:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was using same methods and I got same error. And I fixed it by implementing OnMapReadyCallback.

Firstly implement OnMapReadyCallback:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ......
    ....
```

New setUpMapIfNeeded() method:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mf.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

And call setUpMap() in overrided onMapReady:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}
```

There is no change in setUpMap() method or other methods. I hope it helps.